# Poor performance with concurrent shell commands in Kotlin compared to Java

Tags: java, concurrency, kotlin

I have a strange problem in which I am seeing very poor performance from Kotlin code running concurrent shell commands to extract a file. However, when running the same shell commands using Java code, the performance is as expected.

The difference is VERY significant, with the Java code running in 10-20 seconds, and the Kotlin code running in about 13 minutes.

The particular use case is a function that spawns 15 threads, which all call this extract function to unpack the same tar.gz file. When the call is to the Kotlin function, the performance is poor; when it is Java, the performance is as expected.

The Kotlin code that I have decompiled to Java is nearly identical to the Java code that is performant, with the only difference being the addition of Kotlin Intrinsics, which should not affect performance.

Kotlin Code:

```
@Synchronized
@Throws(IOException::class)
fun extractTar(tarFile: Path, extractPath: Path) {
    logger.info("Extracting file: " + tarFile.toString())
    logger.info("Destination path: " + extractPath.toString())
    val start = System.currentTimeMillis()
    val untarCommand = Arrays.asList("tar", "-xzf", tarFile.toString(), "-C", extractPath.toString())
    val untarProcess = ProcessBuilder()
            .command(untarCommand)
            .redirectErrorStream(true)
            .start()
    waitAndCheckProcessOutput(untarProcess, "tar -xzf ${tarFile.toString()} -C ${extractPath.toString()}", 15)

    logger.info("Running chmod on folder:" + extractPath.toString())
    val chmodCommand = Arrays.asList("chmod", "-R", "0777", extractPath.toString())
    val chmodProcess = ProcessBuilder()
            .command(chmodCommand)
            .redirectErrorStream(true)
            .start()
    waitAndCheckProcessOutput(chmodProcess, "chmod -R 0777 ${extractPath.toString()}", 15)

    logger.info("Extracted in " + printTime(System.currentTimeMillis() - start))
}

fun waitAndCheckProcessOutput(process: Process, command: String, timeoutInMinutes: Long) {
    try {
        val finished = process.waitFor(timeoutInMinutes, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
        if (!finished) {
            logger.info("Timed out running command $command")
        }
        val output = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(process.inputStream))
                .lines()
                .collect(Collectors.joining())
        val exitCode = process.exitValue()
        if (exitCode != 0) {
            logger.info("Got exit code " + exitCode + " running command " + command
                    + "\nGot output:\n" + output)
        }
    } catch (e: InterruptedException) {
        logger.info("Interrupted running command $command" + e)
    }
}

fun printTime(timeInMillis: Long): String {
    var duration = Duration.ofMillis(timeInMillis)
    val minutes = duration.toMinutes()
    duration = duration.minusMinutes(minutes)
    val seconds = duration.seconds
    duration = duration.minusSeconds(seconds)
    val millis = duration.toMillis()
    return minutes.toString() + "m " + seconds + "." + millis + "s"
}
```

Kotlin code decompiled to Java:

```
public final synchronized void extractTar(@NotNull Path tarFile, @NotNull Path extractPath) throws IOException {
  Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull(tarFile, "tarFile");
  Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull(extractPath, "extractPath");

  logger.info("Extracting file: " + tarFile.toString());
  logger.info("Destination path: " + extractPath.toString());
  long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
  List untarCommand = Arrays.asList("tar", "-xzf", tarFile.toString(), "-C", extractPath.toString());
  Process untarProcess = (new ProcessBuilder(new String[0]))
      .command(untarCommand)
      .redirectErrorStream(true)
      .start();
  Intrinsics.checkExpressionValueIsNotNull(untarProcess, "untarProcess");
  this.waitAndCheckProcessOutput(untarProcess, "tar -xzf " + tarFile.toString() + " -C " + extractPath.toString(), 15L);

  logger.info("Running chmod on folder:" + extractPath.toString());
  List chmodCommand = Arrays.asList("chmod", "-R", "0777", extractPath.toString());
  Process chmodProcess = (new ProcessBuilder(new String[0]))
      .command(chmodCommand)
      .redirectErrorStream(true)
      .start();
  Intrinsics.checkExpressionValueIsNotNull(chmodProcess, "chmodProcess");
  this.waitAndCheckProcessOutput(chmodProcess, "chmod -R 0777 " + extractPath.toString(), 15L);
  logger.info("Extracted in " + this.printTime(System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
}

public final void waitAndCheckProcessOutput(@NotNull Process process, @NotNull String command, long timeoutInMinutes) {
  Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull(process, "process");
  Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull(command, "command");
  try {
      boolean finished = process.waitFor(timeoutInMinutes, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
      if (!finished) {
        logger.info("Timed out running command " + command);
      }
      String output = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()))
        .lines()
        .collect(Collectors.joining());
      int exitCode = process.exitValue();
      if (exitCode != 0) {
        logger.info("Got exit code " + exitCode + " running command " + command + "\nGot output:\n" + output);
      }
  } catch (InterruptedException var8) {
      logger.info("Interrupted running command " + command + var8);
  }

}

@NotNull
public final String print(long timeInMillis) {
  Duration duration = Duration.ofMillis(timeInMillis);
  long minutes = duration.toMinutes();
  duration = duration.minusMinutes(minutes);
  long seconds = duration.getSeconds();
  duration = duration.minusSeconds(seconds);
  long millis = duration.toMillis();
  return minutes + "m " + seconds + "." + millis + "s";
}
```

Java code:

```
public static synchronized Path untarFile(Path tarFile, Path extractPath) throws IOException {
    logger.info("Extracting file: " + tarFile.toString());
    logger.info("Destination path: " + extractPath.toString());
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    List<String> untarCommand = Arrays.asList("tar", "-xzf", tarFile.toString(), "-C", extractPath.toString());
    Process untarProcess = new ProcessBuilder()
        .command(untarCommand)
        .redirectErrorStream(true)
        .start();
    ProcessUtil.waitAndCheckProcessOutput(untarProcess, "tar -xzf " + tarFile.toString() + " -C " + extractPath.toString());

    logger.info("Running chmod on folder:" + extractPath.toString());
    List<String> chmodCommand = Arrays.asList("chmod", "-R", "0777", extractPath.toString());
    Process chmodProcess = new ProcessBuilder()
        .command(chmodCommand)
        .redirectErrorStream(true)
        .start();
    ProcessUtil.waitAndCheckProcessOutput(chmodProcess, "chmod -R 0777 " + extractPath.toString());

    logger.info("Extracted in " + TimeUtil.print(System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
    return extractPath;
}

// In ProcessUtil.java
public static void waitAndCheckProcessOutput(Process process, String command, long timeoutInMinutes) {
    try {
        boolean finished = process.waitFor(timeoutInMinutes, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        if (!finished) {
            logger.info("Timed out running command " + command);
        }
        String output = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()))
            .lines()
            .collect(Collectors.joining());
        int exitCode = process.exitValue();
        if (exitCode != 0) {
            logger.info("Got exit code " + exitCode + " running command " + command
                                            + "\nGot output:\n" + output);
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        logger.info("Interrupted running command " + command, e);
    }
}

// in TimeUtil.java
public static String print(long timeInMillis) {
    Duration duration = Duration.ofMillis(timeInMillis);
    long minutes = duration.toMinutes();
    duration = duration.minusMinutes(minutes);
    long seconds = duration.getSeconds();
    duration = duration.minusSeconds(seconds);
    long millis = duration.toMillis();
    return minutes + "m " + seconds + "." + millis + "s";
}
```

It is called like this:

```
IntStream.range(0, count).parallel().forEach{ unsynchronizedMethod() }
```

where extractTar is called within this unsynchronizedMethod.

I'm 95% sure that the slowdown is not occurring in the Intrinsic library calls, as none of the values checked should ever be null.

It is also interesting to note that the slowdown does not occur for small amounts of threads, such as 2. As the number of threads increases, the performance deteriorates, which leads me to suspect that this is actually a concurrency problem.

I have also tried running the Kotlin-decompiled-to-Java code, stripping out the Intrinsic library calls, and that code has the same performance as the native Java code.

Comment: Can you please show the code that calls the `extractTar` function?

Comment: IntStream.range(0, count).parallel().forEach{extractTar(tarPath, extractPath)}

called from a Java file

Comment: The java method is static but the Kotlin method isn't. And they're both synchronized (although on different monitors) so it's not clear what benefits you are thinking to achieve by running them with parallel streams a only one thread at a time can be in the method. (Unless you are invoking the nothin method on different objects )

Comment: Sorry, the extract method is actually being called from within a different unsynchronized method. Have edited the question to reflect this more clearly

Comment: I don't see how it matters that you're calling it from an unsynchronized method. The method itself is synchronized, so the operations will not be performed in parallel.

Comment: The problem persists even when removing synchronized from the extract method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by moving extract into

```
companion object {}
```

Not sure why this fixed the problem, but it did